# Hikari pool connection elided,and open new pools

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I have a spring boot(2.4) applicationUnder long running jpa transactions ,I see a lot connection more than my maximum pool size ,when I checked my logs,I see connection elided,and after than new HikariPools 2-3-4 etc... are opened.
I tried hikari 4.0.2 version but still same issue.In this scenario what is the meaning of giving maximum pool size(Each pools seems my maximum pool size but total connection count is more than my limit).Is there any configuration to limit opening pool counts?
I create datasource like that with code

```
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
dataSource.setJdbcUrl(myuri);
 dataSource.setUsername(myuser);
 dataSource.setPassword(mypasswprd);
 dataSource.setMinimumIdle(10);
 dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
 dataSource.setIdleTimeout(100000);
 dataSource.setMaxLifetime(200000);
 return dataSource;
```

Regards

```
HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 3, queue 5

17:54:56.894 [restartedMain] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@4c6d3cfb
17:54:56.999 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
17:54:57.669 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@190a0b35
17:54:58.314 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@69a59932
17:54:58.314 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After adding stats (total=3, active=0, idle=3, waiting=0)
17:56:57.005 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
17:56:57.005 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
17:57:27.006 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
17:57:27.006 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
18:15:03.114 [http-nio-8085-exec-2] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 4, queue 5
18:15:03.126 [http-nio-8085-exec-17] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 4, queue 5
18:15:03.130 [http-nio-8085-exec-18] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 3, queue 5
18:15:03.248 [http-nio-8085-exec-11] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 3, queue 5
18:15:03.254 [http-nio-8085-exec-8] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 3, queue 5
18:15:03.288 [http-nio-8085-exec-17] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 3, queue 5
18:15:03.289 [http-nio-8085-exec-8] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 2, queue 5
18:15:03.291 [http-nio-8085-exec-11] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 3, queue 5
18:15:03.326 [http-nio-8085-exec-8] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Add connection
18:15:03.391 [http-nio-8085-exec-12] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-2 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@4f5ab95d
18:15:03.538 [HikariPool-2 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-2 - Pool stats (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=1)
18:15:03.938 [http-nio-8085-exec-6] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-3 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@4e5ee0cc
18:15:04.040 [HikariPool-3 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-3 - Pool stats (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=1)
18:15:04.167 [HikariPool-2 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-2 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@317680ec
18:15:04.225 [http-nio-8085-exec-5] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-4 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@79d11005
```

Comment: afaik the default config doesn't do this, so you must be doing something out of the default to make this happen. Please add some code/configuration to your question.

Comment: Hi I added code sample to question ,I use spring jpa in my jpa context I set datasource with code like this

Comment: You are just posting snippets which makes it impossible to get the full picture. You are using Spring Boot so why not **use** Spring Boot. Just add the configuration to your `application.properties` and ditch this explicitly configured datasource.

Comment: I have to pull password etc from my vault,for that reason I create datasource with code,but is it important because with code or config ,is there any idea to fix this issue

Comment: Spring Boot can get stuff from a vault quite easily without you needing to manually configure everything. But as stated there is too little information to try to answer this. The fact that you manually configure things, also means you are configuring other things manually and thus differently.

Comment: In my case I need to do this with code,if you have any about to cause this case or,Do you see any specific item to configure ,or should be added or not,can you add?thanks

Comment: Again there is too little information to be able to answer that. As I stated the fact that you manually configure things, will also mean you are configuring other things manually (and thus differently). Without seeing the whole picture answering this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In my code there is a leakage,I create datasource more than once for that reason I see multiple datasource